# Opengl framebuffer separate stencil texture

Tags: c++, opengl

I cannot find any documentation for a separate stencil texture for framebuffer objects. Basically here is what I have so far:

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->mTextures[FRAMEBUFFER_STENCIL_TEXTURE]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R8I, width, height, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT,  GL_TEXTURE_2D, this->mTextures[FRAMEBUFFER_STENCIL_TEXTURE],    0);
```

But this causes a creation error. Is my format wrong or is it something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, those format values are wrong for a stencil texture. You need to use specific stencil enums for both the *internalFormat* and *format*. The call should look like this for an 8-bit stencil texture:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_STENCIL_INDEX8,
             width, height, 0, GL_STENCIL_INDEX, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
```

As has been pointed out in comments, pure stencil textures are only available in OpenGL 4.4 and higher.

An alternative is to allocate a depth/stencil texture, and just not use the depth part. However, sampling from the stencil part of a depth/stencil texture requires OpenGL 4.3 or higher, so that only reduces the version requirement by one minor version.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I tried it but it still crashes unfortunately. I managed to find this on the opengl official docs but it appears this is for opengl 4.4+ only... I am on opengl 2, so am I stuck with depth and stencil combined textures only?

Comment: @Jas OpenGL 2.x does not have framebuffer objects, so none of this applies there.

Comment: Well I am using shader versions 130 which are supposed to be for opengl 2 I think... But I do have access to framebuffer objects.

Comment: @Jas: OK, before we can go any farther with this, you *need* to know what you're actually using. An implementation of OpenGL 2.0 will not take a GLSL 1.30 shader. It will choke on the `#version 130` declaration. So you need to work out what you *actually* have.

Comment: GLSL 1.30 goes along with OpenGL 3.0. I wasn't aware that stencil textures were as recent as 4.4. However, after looking it up, sampling from the stencil part of a depth/stencil texture requires 4.3, so that would be the minimum version required to sample stencil values from a texture in any case.